# React-redux ownprops is emtpy, so I can not get match and params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom

I am working with `react-redux` and I used routers turn pages to detail.js when I put the todo list.

It should have `ownprops` properties on consoles, but mine was not defined.

Tell me where we're wrong.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Detail from "../routes/Detail";
import Home from "../routes/Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/:id" element={<Detail />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Todos.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { actionCreators } from '../store';

function Todo({ text, onBtnClick, id }) {
  return (
    <li>
      <Link to={`/${id}`}>{text}</Link>
      <button onClick={onBtnClick}>delete</button>
    </li>
  );
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
  console.log(ownProps);
  return {
    onBtnClick: () => dispatch(actionCreators.deleteToDo(ownProps.id)),
  };
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Todo); // 삭제는 state를 상관할 필요 x
```

Details.js

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

function Detail({ toDo }) {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{toDo?.text}</h1>
      <h5>Created at: {toDo?.id}</h5>
    </>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  console.log("ownProps: ", ownProps);
  const {
    match: {
      params: { id },
    },
  } = ownProps.match.params;
  console.log("id: ", id);
  return { toDos: state.find((toDo) => toDo.id === parseInt(id)) };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Detail);
```

Home.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Todo from "../components/ToDo";
import { actionCreators } from "../store";

function Home({ toDos, addTodo }) {
  // we are creating props

  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  function onChange(e) {
    setText(e.target.value);
  }

  function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addTodo(text);
    console.log(text);
    setText("");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>To Do</h1>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input type="text" value={text} onChange={onChange} />
        <button>Add</button>
        <ul>
          {toDos.map((toDo) => (
            <Todo {...toDo} key={toDo.id} />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { toDos: state };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { addTodo: (text) => dispatch(actionCreators.addToDo(text)) };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import App from "./components/App";
import store from "./store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

store.js

```js
import { createStore } from "redux";

const ADD = "ADD";
const DELETE = "DELETE";

const addToDo = (text) => {
  return {
    type: ADD,
    text,
  };
};

const deleteToDo = (id) => {
  return {
    type: DELETE,
    id: parseInt(id),
  };
};

const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD:
      return [{ text: action.text, id: Date.now() }, ...state];
    case DELETE:
      return state.filter((toDo) => toDo.id !== action.id);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = createStore(reducer);

// store.subscribe(); 변화가 있으면 re-render하기 바람.

export const actionCreators = {
  addToDo,
  deleteToDo,
};

export default store;
```

I have no idea, personally I think I have followed below tutorial and router could not be same with them, the errors occurred.

https://nomadcoders.co/redux-for-beginners/lectures/1620

Answer (score 1):

You are using old React Redux code/patterns and `react-router-dom` doesn't provide any props route props (*e.g. there is no `match` prop*) to components. Use the React hooks from both `react-redux` and `react-router-dom` to access the `id` route path parameter and redux state selections.

Example:

Detail

```
<Route path="/:id" element={<Detail />} /> // no additional props passed
```

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function Detail() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const todo = useSelector(state => state.find(todo => String(todo.id) === id));

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{todo?.text}</h1>
      <h5>Created at: {todo?.id}</h5>
    </>
  );
}

export default Detail;
```

Home

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Todo from "../components/ToDo";
import { actionCreators } from '../store';

function Home() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const todos = useSelector(state => state);

  // we are creating props

  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  function onChange(e) {
    setText(e.target.value);
  }

  function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(actionCreators.addTodo(text));
    setText("");
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>To Do</h1>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input type="text" value={text} onChange={onChange} />
        <button>Add</button>
        <ul>
          {todos.map((todo) => (
            <Todo {...todo} key={todo.id} />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Todo

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { actionCreators } from '../store';

function Todo({ text, id }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onBtnClick = () => {
    dispatch(actionCreators.deleteTodo(id));
  };

  return (
    <li>
      <Link to={`/${id}`}>{text}</Link>
      <button onClick={onBtnClick}>delete</button>
    </li>
  );
}

export default Todo;
```

[image: Edit nifty-rain-1r8gdw]

Comment: I applied your code and it still does not work, and the error occured: Error in /~/src/routes/Home.js (43:41)
store_1.actionCreators.addTodo is not a function

Comment: @Yeoo0 It would certainly appear that the `addTodo` is exported out on the `actionCreators` object from the store.

Comment: @Yeoo0 Sorry, it was a casing issue. There's an `actionCreators.addToDo` and I was using `actionCreators.addTodo`. Here's a running [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-rain-1r8gdw?file=/src/App.js:198-261) with consistent casing.

Comment: it works perfect! thank you! I've been headache for a few days.

Comment: @Yeoo0 No worries. Sorry my typo caused more confusion. Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[Drew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75717537/4364635) detailing how to use the updated pattern would be the preferred solution, but if for some reason this is not feasible and you are on at least React 16.8+ you can recreate a version of the `withRouter` HOC.

This is detailed in the [React Router FAQ](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it), but for completeness the code snippet is as follows:

```
import {
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";

function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        router={{ location, navigate, params }}
      />
    );
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}
```

When using the `withRouter` HOC along side the `connect` HOC you will need to ensure they are used in the correct order to allow for the the Redux mapping functions to access the router properties.

For example:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  console.log("ownProps: ", ownProps);
  const { id } = ownProps.router.params;
  console.log("id: ", id);
  return { toDos: state.find((toDo) => toDo.id === parseInt(id)) };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Detail));
```